# how to read html and post a form and read response with one connection

Tags: python, html, post, request

as the title says.

I am trying to do the following:

OpenUrl, Read Html, Post Form, Read Response

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml

This shows that i can read the html:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read()
```

And i can post a request:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

The thing is, how do i combine these two within a single connection? I need to be able to read the html before i open the req for the response.

What am i not seeing :P?

EDIT:

So i tried to do them in order, as expected it didnt work as i wanted it to.

There is a value in the html that needs to be send with the POST, but this value changes when you open the url again.

So my question is, is there a way to open a connection, read the html and post stuff while that single connection is open? And not do urlopen twice?

Answer (score 0):

maybe I don't understand, but does this work?

```
import urllib
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read()

# maybe do some html parsing here ?

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Comment: I actually didnt try it, but i think by the looks of it, it opens the url and closes the connection, and then does a post?

I actually want to do this within a single connection.

But then again, i didnt try it yet so.. ill get this script to the point where i can actually tell if it works or not (with the parsing).

Comment: So i tried to do them in order, as expected it didnt work as i wanted it to.

There is a value in the html that needs to be send with the POST, but this value changes when you open the url again.

So my question is, is there a way to open a connection, read the html and post stuff while that single connection is open? And not do urlopen twice?

Comment: @user3603865 -- I'm not sure what you mean by "a single connection".  Generally, you send a request and you get a response.  Do you need to deal with persistent data like cookies?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but i found my answer here:
http://splinter.cobrateam.info/en/latest/

Basically i need a webbrowser controller.
What i wanted to do cannot be achieved with whats written above.

This is what i wanted to avoid tho, a webbrowser controller.
But whatever works, works.